# Frequency of values of an array

Tags: c, arrays

I am trying to create a program that will count the frequency of 10 numbers that i will choose but when i am trying to run it it doesn't even run the printf and closes.Any ideas? thanks

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{ 
  int i,j,A[10]={0},C[10]={0};
  for(i=0;i<10;i++)
  {
     scanf("%d /n",&A[i]);
  }
  for(j=0;j<10;j++)
  {
     if(A[i]==j)
     {
        C[j]=C[j]+1;
        printf(" %d ",C[j]);
        break;
     }
   }
   getch();
 }
```

Comment: `A[i]==j` is A[10]==j

Comment: What do you mean, just closes!? have you tried printing something outside of the loops? Also, it's `\n`, and not `/n`

Comment: `C[j]=C[j]+1` can be written as `C[j]++`, which is much shorter and easy to read & understand.

Comment: `scanf("%d /n",&A[i]);` I don't think you meant to type a `'/'` and an `'n'` after each number. You probably intended `\n` here, but the `%d` conversion skips leading whitespace, so it should be just `scanf("%d", &A[i]);` with no whitespace in the format string.

Answer (score 1):

The line

```
if(A[i]==j)
```

looks wrong - `i` was the counter for a previous loop and is now 10 (so beyond the bounds of your array).  Did you mean

```
if(A[j]==j)
//   ^
```

instead?

Changing this makes the program run for me.  I don't think it does what you want yet.  The `break` statement causes execution to halt the first time you find any match.

Hopefully this is enough hints to allow you to investigate how to count frequency of the numbers then print them all out yourself.

Comment: I replaced the i with the j but it seems to print only the value with the highest frequency.I want to have an output like this : if i enter for instance the values {3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 2 2} to get  8,2

Comment: See the paragraph in my answer about removing the `break` statement.  You should separate loops to count the frequency of values then report the frequencies

Comment: Ok really weird stuff is happening.Sometimes even when i try to run the program with only replacing the i with j it doesn't run...  That code was given to me from my teacher and he told me to just run it.I bet he was wrong....again.Can you run it with every combination of numbers?because i can't

Answer (score 0):

You need to again loop over the A array in order to check the value of each element:

```
for(i=0;i<10;i++)
{
    for(j=0;j<10;j++)
    {
         if(A[i]==j)
         {
             C[j]=C[j]+1;
             printf(" %d ",C[j]);
             break;
         }
     }
}
```

If you know that the values in A will range from 0-9 then you could completely remove the inner loop and just do `C[A[i]]++;`

After this your C array will contain a count of each number the user input. e.g. `C[5]` will contain the number of 5s found, so you can output this as you see fit